# Javascript promise/then not executing in correct order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Here's the code:

```
vm.saveData = function(data) {

             demoService.saveData(data, function(response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    principal.identity(true).then(function() {
                        $state.reload();
                        return toastr.success('Success');
                    });

                }
                return toastr.error('Failure');
            });
}
```

On getting success response from the api, it should display only the 'success' message. But, instead it displays the 'failure' message first and then the 'success' message. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to put a timeout or is there something which I'm missing here?

Comment: Return error in an `else`.

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest solution and it's working too. If i use else then i might simply use toastr to display message and remove return from there. But I know that I'm doing something wrong which is why .then is not working. I just wanted to know where my fault lies.

Comment: Best explanation of promises: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Answer (score 1):

If the status is 200 then you set up a promise to call `success` later on.

Regardless of what the status is (because it is outside of the `if` and you haven't used an `else`) you always call `error`.

Presumably you just want to move `return toastr.error('Failure');` into an `else`

Comment: The error message is called only when the status is not equal to 200.

Comment: @Samridhi — Incorrect. See the second paragraph of this answer, in particular the section in parenthesis, which explains why.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you setup promises. Promises uses `.then()`. You are simply using passing the function in as a callback.

```
vm.saveData = function(data) {

  demoService
    .saveData(data)
    .then(success, error);

  function success(response) {
    principal.identity(true).then(function() {
      $state.reload();
      return toastr.success('Success');
    });
  }

  function error(response) {
    return toastr.error('Failure');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Many systems such as AJAX send multiple messages to indicate progress in the task.  You want to ignore the earlier messages.  The failure message is from the earlier events while the action is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my mistake. Adding 'return' resolved the issue.

'return principal.identity(true).then(function(){

//do something here

});'

```
vm.saveData = function(data) {

             demoService.saveData(data, function(response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return principal.identity(true).then(function() {
                        $state.reload();
                        return toastr.success('Success');
                    });

                }
                return toastr.error('Failure');
            });
}
```